How to preprocess dataset to assign coordinates before opening with xarray.open_mfdataset?
The xarray documentation for the open_mfdataset function states that you can use the preprocess argument to apply a function to each dataset before concatenation. The NetCDF datasets I have do not have coordinates assigned when you open them one-by-one, so I was attempting to assign them before concatenation with combine='by_coords' in the open_mfdataset function.
This is what a single one of the datasets looks like if you open it:
path = 'path/to/my/file/file.nc'
ds = xr.open_dataset(path, decode_times=False)
ds

# <xarray.Dataset> Size: 1GB
# Dimensions:       (comid: 2677612, time_mn: 120, time_yr: 10)
# Dimensions without coordinates: comid, time_mn, time_yr
#Data variables:
#    COMID         (comid) int32 11MB ...
#    Time_mn       (time_mn) int32 480B ...
#    Time_yr       (time_yr) int32 40B ...
#    RAPID_mn_cfs  (comid, time_mn) float32 1GB ...
#    RAPID_yr_cfs  (comid, time_yr) float32 107MB ...

To use open_mfdataset my code looks like this. The assignCoordinates function works as intended, but it still fails to open the datasets.
def assignCoordinates(df):
    df = df.assign_coords({
        "comid": df['COMID'], 
        "time_mn": fd.calcDatetimes(df, 'Time_mn', df.sizes['time_mn']), #this just calculates datetimes for the weird time units used in these files, the function works properly
        "time_yr": fd.calcDatetimes(df, 'Time_yr', df.sizes['time_yr'])
    })
    return df

path = "path/to/files/*.nc"
ds = xr.open_mfdataset(path, preprocess=assignCoordinates, combine='by_coords', decode_times=False)

ds

This is the error I receive:
ValueError: Could not find any dimension coordinates to use to order the datasets for concatenation

I assume the preprocessed files are not actually being used by open_mfdataset, but then I don't really understand what the point of that argument is. My suspicion that it doesn't use the preprocessed datasets is further enforced by the fact that if it was, I should be able to remove decode_times=False because the times are now calculated in a way that makes sense and could be decoded after running through the assignCoordinates function, but if I remove it, I get an error about the times being unable to be decoded.
Is there a way to do what I am wanting or do I really have to open each dataset individually?
Minimum Reproducible Example
Copy this code, and fill out the export path. This will create three .nc files in the directory you specify.
import xarray as xr 
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
temperature = 15 + 8 * np.random.randn(2, 3, 4)
precipitation = 10 * np.random.rand(2, 3, 4)
lon = [-99.83, -99.32]
lat = [42.25, 42.21]
instruments = ["manufac1", "manufac2", "manufac3"]
time = pd.date_range("2014-09-06", periods=4)
reference_time = pd.Timestamp("2014-09-05")
ds = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars=dict(
        temperature=(["loc", "instrument", "time"], temperature),
        precipitation=(["loc", "instrument", "time"], precipitation),
    ),
    attrs=dict(description="Weather related data."),
)
for i in range(1,4):
    ds.to_netcdf(f'yourdirectory/test{i}.nc') #### EDIT HERE #####

After doing the above, run this code (remember to alter the directory to where you saved the files created above):
def assignCoordinates(df):
    df = df.assign_coords({
        "loc": df['loc'],
        "instrument": df['instrument'],
        "time": df['time']
    })
    return df

ds = xarr.open_mfdataset('yourdirectory/*.nc', preprocess=assignCoordinates, combine='by_coords') #### EDIT HERE #####
ds


You don't save any time coordinates in your dataset. You should write:
ds = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars=dict(
        temperature=(["loc", "instrument", "time"], temperature),
        precipitation=(["loc", "instrument", "time"], precipitation),
    ),
    coords={'time': time},
    attrs=dict(description="Weather related data."),
)

Additionally, the time for each dataset saved in your loop must be different if you want to concatenate along this dimension in the open_mfdataset.

I think the example dataset I submitted threw you off. I did not create these datasets and they open without coordinates, so the goal is to assign coordinates before opening with mfdataset as the preprocess kwarg suggest you might be able to do. The reproducible example I provided was so you could create a few datasets without coordinates quickly and see the problem I am experiencing with trying to use preprocess. It was not intended that you edit the xr.Dataset call because that's not the use case given I am consuming the "real" datasets I am trying to use, not creating them myself.
